# dip switch electric shield

Tags: relay, shielding

I have ordered a Reed Relay with a diode and electric shield, but I am not sure how to connect the shield to the rest of the circuit because I do not know what the shield does and how does it work in the context of the DIP Switch. Does anyone have any insights on this?

[image]

This is the data sheet with more information:
https://docs-apac.rs-online.com/webdocs/1398/0900766b813980c8.pdf

Comment: Link to the data sheet would help us.

Comment: That is not a DIP switch, that is a reed relay. http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=108-98011&DocType=SS&DocLang=EN. The package is called "DIP". A "DIP Switch" usually refers to a physical switch like this: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/dip-switch-4.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, that is actually a reed relay. The package it comes in is called DIP (dual in-line package) since it conforms to a certain spacing on the pins. The purpose of the electrostatic shield in the context of the relay is to reduce interference on the signal going through the relay when the relay coil engages (which generates a magnetic field and can induce a current in the relay contacts). The resulting current appears as noise in the signal, especially if the signal is being measured by something either very sensitive or fairly high-impedance.

Quoting from an application note I found after googling, which notes how to connect the shield:

> **Electrostatic Shield**
>
> Used to reduce any noise or electrostatic coupling that may
> occur between the coil of a relay and the internal magnetic
> reed switch. The electrostatic shield normally consists of
> copper, terminated to a designated pin externally connected
> to ground.

Source: [http://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/application_notes/reed_switches/littelfuse_magnetic_sensors_and_reed_switches_catalog_glossary_reed_switch_terms_application_note.pdf.pdf](http://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/application_notes/reed_switches/littelfuse_magnetic_sensors_and_reed_switches_catalog_glossary_reed_switch_terms_application_note.pdf.pdf)